# Importing data from spreadsheet into wordpress DB, along with custom taxonomies and their terms

Tags: posts, taxonomy, terms, import

I am importing a large DB from an Excel spreadsheet into a wordpress DB. I was going to do it manually by creating a new table but decided to import it into the existing wordpress framework as it will allow me to change information manually in the wordpress back end.

I was importing all 2000 rows into the wp_posts table when I realised this table doesnt have a term column. The terms are stored in other tables.

My question is... how can I import the spreadsheet into the database and keep all of the important data, especially the terms, as my site queries all information by the "term" and uses jQuery tabs to display the different terms as sub-categories.

My information looks like this:

```
post-title(title)---category(term)---description(content)---imageUrl---price
```

Note: I will create a seperate column in the wp_posts table to handle the price, or any other information I need bringing in, Im just unsure about how I can get the term information into the corresponding tables...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should create a new column in wp_posts...

This kind of info is stored in wp_postmeta.

When I need this kind of importing (Excel->WP), I use [CSV Importer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/other_notes/), as you can assign categories, tags and custom field to the imported data.
You'll probably need to do a couple of tests with few entries until get the right CSV format.

And maybe, you'll also need to manipulate the CSV in an advanced text editor before importing (as Microsoft software is not always that smart).

Comment: Ok thats a great suggestion. Ive downloaded the plugin and it seems to work, except it doesnt carry over the terms for the taxonomy. If I understand this right, I am making terms as categories of a taxonomy. I only have 1 taxonomy, and use get_temrs() to pull in and display the terms as categories.

Comment: well, you can put as many categories, tags, custom taxonomies and custom fields for each post, page and custom post type you are importing... i don't understand this "it doesn't carry over the terms for the taxonomy"... (?)

Answer (score -1):

[TurboCSV](http://wphostreviews.com/product/turbocsv) is my go-to. Works with custom taxonomies as well.